# Css3 hover menu

Tags: css, menu, hover

is it possible to hover an image and visible other css element such as menu links:

```
<div class="carousel">    
   <div class="row" style="margin-top:60px;">
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-7 text-left" > <div class="logo"></div> </div>
       <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-4 text-right" id="mymenu" style="padding-right:80px;"> 
                <a href="#" class="m">HOME</a>   <span class="d">|</span> 
                <a href="#" class="m">ABOUT</a>  <span class="d">|</span> 
                <a href="#" class="m">CONTACT</a>
                <a href="#" class="m"> </a>
        </div>


            <div class="col-md-1" id="myimg">   
                 <img src="images/menu.JPG">  </div>
           </div>

                          ...]
```

Once I hover image (menu.jpg) I want to visible menu links (home contact etc.) gradually to the left like a drawer. I use bootsrap.
My CSS code is:

```
#mymenu a.m, .d {

        font-size:22px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#000;
        display:none;
    }

    .carousel #myimg img:hover > .carousel  #mymenu a.m{
        display:block;
        }
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post complete HTML or create fiddle.

Comment: Using JavaScript, yes. Without using JavaScript (only CSS), no, unless it is a descendant or a sibling of the target element. afaik.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to affect other elements when a div is hovered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered)

Comment: Any help..? When I hover an image I want to display a menu behind..

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks!